# The TActionMainMenuBar main menu item switch stutters in Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, menu, delphi-7

I use a TActionToolBar with a TActionMainMenuBar in a Delphi 7 project. When I'm browsing one main menu and I want to change to one another (4ex file to edit) I have to click twice on the another menu item for the change (1., close the first, 2., open the new sub menu). With TMainMenu this is seamless, enough just move over the another menu item, the submenu changes automatically. What messages should I override, or what api calls should I make to realize a TMainMenu like behaviour? There must be a solution because the Delphi 7 IDE uses the same component and its behaviour is right.

The date of the dclact70.bpl : 10.08.2002 (dd.mm.yyyy)

The Unit1.pas:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, ActnList, XPStyleActnCtrls, ActnMan, ToolWin, ActnCtrls,
  ActnMenus;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ActionMainMenuBar1: TActionMainMenuBar;
    ActionManager1: TActionManager;
    Action1: TAction;
    Action1_1: TAction;
    Action1_2: TAction;
    Action2: TAction;
    Action2_1: TAction;
    Action2_2: TAction;
    procedure emptyActionHandler(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.emptyActionHandler(Sender: TObject);
begin
//
end;

end.
```

The unit1.dfm:

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 584
  Top = 180
  Width = 870
  Height = 640
  Caption = 'Form1'
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'MS Sans Serif'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object ActionMainMenuBar1: TActionMainMenuBar
    Left = 0
    Top = 0
    Width = 854
    Height = 29
    ActionManager = ActionManager1
    Caption = 'ActionMainMenuBar1'
    ColorMap.HighlightColor = clWhite
    ColorMap.BtnSelectedColor = clBtnFace
    ColorMap.UnusedColor = clWhite
    Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
    Font.Color = clMenuText
    Font.Height = -12
    Font.Name = 'Segoe UI'
    Font.Style = []
    Spacing = 0
  end
  object ActionManager1: TActionManager
    ActionBars = <
      item
        Items = <
          item
            Items = <
              item
                Action = Action1_1
                Caption = '&Action1_1'
              end
              item
                Action = Action1_2
                Caption = 'A&ction1_2'
              end>
            Action = Action1
            Caption = '&Action1'
          end
          item
            Items = <
              item
                Action = Action2_1
              end
              item
                Action = Action2_2
              end>
            Action = Action2
            Caption = 'A&ction2'
          end>
        ActionBar = ActionMainMenuBar1
      end
      item
        Items = <
          item
            Action = Action2_1
          end
          item
            Action = Action2_2
          end>
      end>
    Left = 8
    Top = 40
    StyleName = 'XP Style'
    object Action1: TAction
      Caption = 'Action1'
      OnExecute = emptyActionHandler
    end
    object Action1_1: TAction
      Category = 'ac1'
      Caption = 'Action1_1'
      OnExecute = emptyActionHandler
    end
    object Action1_2: TAction
      Category = 'ac1'
      Caption = 'Action1_2'
      OnExecute = emptyActionHandler
    end
    object Action2: TAction
      Caption = 'Action2'
      OnExecute = emptyActionHandler
    end
    object Action2_1: TAction
      Category = 'ac2'
      Caption = 'Action2_1'
      OnExecute = emptyActionHandler
    end
    object Action2_2: TAction
      Category = 'ac2'
      Caption = 'Action2_2'
      OnExecute = emptyActionHandler
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: You need to include a [mcve] so we can reproduce the issue. It works fine for me in dozens of applications.

Comment: Is there any way to attache a rar/zip here? I just insert a TActionMainMenuBar and a TActionManager to the form of an empty project. Creating some actions and linking them to the ActionMenu items with no content onExecute event handlers. When it runs, the behaviour is the one describev above. Do you use Delphi 7?

Comment: No. All relevant information needs to be in your question. It's not that difficult to create a [mcve]. Start a new Delphi project, add the relevant components, and generate the OnExecute handlers. Right-click the form and choose *View as Text*, and copy the text. Right-click again and *View as Form* and you're back. Now paste the clipboard contents in here. That's the form portion. Now copy and paste the code, and you're set. We have something to go by here.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed description. It did not come to my mind (View as text). I will do that soon.

Comment: I can confirm your issue with Delphi 7. It doesn't occur in Delphi 2007, in case you could switch to that version.